# How can I get mod_wsgi working on Mac?

Tags: apache, macos, version-control, mercurial

I have been trying to install the latest version of mod_wsgi (3.3) since hours on my Mac. I'm on Snow Leopard and I have the versions of Apache (Apache/2.2.15) and Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515) that come with the system.

1. I downloaded mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz from http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/detail?name=mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz
2. Extracted the file and executed the following through terminal:

   `./configure
   make
   sudo make install`
3. I added LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so to my httpd.conf.
4. Restarted Apache by disabling and enabling Web Sharing from the control panel.
5. localhost stops working until I remove the line I added httpd.conf :(

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use the [homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed version of `mod_wsgi`. That gives me a universal version of `mod_wsgi` that works with the vanilla apache.

```
➔  file `brew list mod_wsgi`
/usr/local/Cellar/mod_wsgi/3.2/libexec/mod_wsgi.so: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/local/Cellar/mod_wsgi/3.2/libexec/mod_wsgi.so (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
/usr/local/Cellar/mod_wsgi/3.2/libexec/mod_wsgi.so (for architecture i386): Mach-O bundle i386
```

Comment: This is out of date.

Comment: Quite possibly.

Comment: Yeah, here is a possible most current solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55503698/6042764

Answer (score 7):

The problem you had was the path to mod_wsgi.so.  On OS X the appropriate line is

```
LoadModule wsgi_module        libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so
```

Answer (score 7):

With the latest Mac OS and most recent HomeBrew, the package isn't available on HomeBrew.

However, if you have Python3 and Pip3 installed and configured on your Mac, you can load the package using:

```
pip3 install mod_wsgi
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to first run the below command to get mod_wsgi installed

```
brew tap homebrew/apache
```

And then run

```
brew install mod_wsgi
```

Comment: This is now out of date: "Warning: homebrew/apache was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated."

Answer (score 4):

On OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, `brew install mod_wsgi` fails. [This answer on stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58186/how-to-compile-mod-wsgi-mod-fastcgi-etc-on-mountain-lion-by-fixing-apxserror) suggests the location of the XCode toolchain has changed. It fixed my problem and hopefully helps other people who end up here on 10.8 trying to install mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this error but I didn't want to use brew.

In my case the cause of the problem was in misconfiguration of python framework used for mod_wsgi that can be checked by
`otool -L /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so`

In my case it pointed to Python 2.7 framework while I was using Python 3.3 and my
`python -> /usr/bin/python`
also pointed to python 3.3 version.

In order to fix this, I removed already installed `/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so` .

Then reconfigured mod_wsgi with command:
`./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python --disable-framework`
`sudo make`
`sudo make install`

This should work fine.
But in my case after executing `make` command I've got a warning about non existing Python framework folder. So I checked what was the real path of my Python framework folder and replaced it in the Makefile under `LDFLAGS`.

Changed from:
`-L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/config`
to
`-L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/config-3.3m`

Good way to check the Apache modules if it doesn't work, is:
`apachectl -M`

If some module causes the error, it will print it.

Comment: Can't you use the `WSGIPythonPath` directive to tell the module which Python to use?

Answer (score 1):

The below solution works for me for MacOS BigSur and Monterey:

Install MacPorts from https://www.macports.org/install.php

`sudo port install mod_wsgi` --> installs apache2, python3 among other things

apachectl location after install: `/opt/local/sbin/apachectl`

apache2 modules location: `/opt/local/lib/apache2/modules/`

httpd config location: `/opt/local/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Add this line to httpd.conf: `LoadModule wsgi_module lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote two tutorials about how to install Apache + MySQL + Python in Mac OS and Windows.
Maybe you can take a look.

[Tutorial] install Apache + MySQL + Python on Mac OS
http://fstoke.me/blog/?p=3583

[Tutorial] install Apache + MySQL + Python on Windows
http://fstoke.me/blog/?p=3600

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X comes with apache 2, to install mod_wsgi just install homebrew and run the following command.

```
*brew install homebrew/apache/mod_wsgi*
```

go to **apache2/modules/** and search for mod_wsgi.so
after this goto **apache2/conf/** and do

```
*sudo vim http.conf*
```

and add the following line
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble getting mod_wsgi to work as well even using different peoples advice and it wasn't working, so I finally used this website: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

1. Downloaded the mod_wsgi 4.5.15 file
2. Opened the file in a location I liked
3. Went to folder location in terminal
4. Did `python3 setup.py install` (or python if you're using a different version)

I have a MacBook Pro Version 10.12.5 in case this helps anyone.